# When modifying a C++ vector, is it best to copy the vector or use a reference with mutex locking?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, mutex

I'm curious about what folks think is the best practice, while considering performance, for iterating over a shared vector and modifying some elements in a multi-threaded C++ program.

For a simple example, suppose I want to periodically replace all instances of 3 with 1 in a shared int vector. There are two options:

1. If I use a reference to the vector, I need to use locks everywhere that manipulates the vector to make sure it doesn't change while I'm iterating through it.
2. I can just copy the vector, iterate freely, then replace the shared vector without doing any locking.

#2 comes with a performance disadvantage due to the additional copy, and I'm wondering how significant people think this is in the average case. The answer is obvious at the extrema, when using either small or very large vectors. But I'd love to hear opinions on what is considered "best practice" here for most use cases. Are there any new alternatives people would suggest here?

Using reference and locking:

```
    void modifyFnLocking() {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(myMutex);

      std::vector<int>& vec = getSharedVector();
      for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++) {
        if (*it == 3) *it = 1;
      }
      replaceSharedVector(vec);
    }
```

Using copying:

```
    void modifyFnCopying() {
      std::vector<int> vec = getSharedVector();
      for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++) {
        if (*it == 3) *it = 1;
      }
      replaceSharedVector(vec);
    }
```

Comment: Unless you can somehow copy and paste atomically, copying approach solves nothing

Comment: Average over what? All existing programs? All executions of all existing programs? All possible programs?

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes I guess I assumed that C++ copy constructors would be atomic, is this wrong? So replaceSharedVector(vec) would then copy the vector into memory via its pointer that is shared between threads.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Sure to any of those questions. As I mentioned, of course there are clear answers on either side of the size spectrum. Looking for open-ended opinions on whether one solution stands out dramatically worse than the other in the cases of non-extreme vector sizes. (e.g. someone may hate locking so much that they'd take #2 at all costs, and I'd love to hear their thoughts on that).

Comment: Yes, that is wrong. Not even assigning a pointer is atomic by default. Is the vector growing? Or does it have the same size?

Comment: The second option still needs some synchronization. You can `std::swap` or `std::vector::swap` two vectors in O(1) time but it needs to be made thread-safe during the swap (a mutex for example). The `getSharedVector()` function needs it too if the vector is being modified during the copy.

Comment: do you really need the whole vector update as atomic?

Comment: @ideanl no copy assignments and similar are not atomic. You need mutexes to do them properly. The question you ask is complex reasonable because it might be that the modification takrs a lot of time and the vector needs to be accessed elsewhere. But what to do when two pieces of code modify their own versions how to merge the differences?

Comment: Thanks for all the useful info on c++ vector copying. I updated examples so that both now will replace the shared vector via copying (doesn't need to be atomic or can be for updating, irrelevant to example). The focus of the question is on the first copy before iterating over the vector to find elements we care to replace.

Comment: In your reference example the call to `replaceSharedVector` seems unnecessary since you are working directly on the shared vector. In your copying version, what should happen with the content of the shared vector  that may have changed while you were working on the copy?

Comment: @ideanl Is the vector changing its size? If not, you could simply use an array of `std::atomic_int` and do without any locking.

Comment: "Looking for open-ended opinions". Wrong site then.

Comment: Concerning best practices, one of them is to document which mutex is responsible for which shared data. First and foremost, this makes you form a plan how things are shared. Also, aggregating data, the according mutex and perhaps condition variable further helps with this. Things like your `getSharedVector()` function should then automatically not happen, though it's hard to say what kind of access there is and where that shared vector and mutex are (global/class, public/private).

Answer (score 0):

#1 is the only way because you can't even copy or assign vector without locking. If this problem arises and several consumers operate on same large data, a vector isn't data structure you require.
To avoid code bloat perhaps some kind of accessor functions might be used to localize lockouts.

Depending on use-case, you may end with a in-memory database of sorts. Atomic access to an array of data is what databases exel at.